# How to enforce dependencies between records within a table on database level

Tags: sql-server, database-design, dependencies

I have a database table, for example:

```
----[Statuses]----
StatusID
Name
------------------
```

With a data example:

```
----[Statuses]----
1
Quote created

2
Quote accepted

3
Quote sent

4
Quote confirmed

5
Quote declined
-------------------
```

Now I'd like to show this in the interface as a multiple choice, so having all these records under each other with a checkbox - however, some options are not multiple choice, like 'Quote confirmed' and 'Quote declined' cannot be both true.

The biggest problem is that this table is variable - users can add more statuses - else I'd be able to create triggers.

How could I enforce this kind of rule on record-level? Is there a way, by adding 1 or more columns into this table, to make it work?

**EDIT:**
I'll add a more complete design regarding my question:

There is another table, like:

```
---[Projects]---
ProjectID
Projectname
Projectcode
Projecttype
----------------
```

In order to record what the user has picked, a junction table is required:

```
------------------[Projects_Statuses]---------------
ProjectID
StatusID
DateChecked (date when the user clicked the status)
UserChecked (user that clicked the status)
-----------------------------------------------------
```

The following could be a result by joining the tables

```
SELECT *
FROM Projects_Statuses PS
   INNER JOIN Statuses S ON PS.StatusID = S.StatusID
   INNER JOIN Projects P ON PS.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
```

RESULT:

```
--------------------[Project_Statuses]-----------------
Project_StatusID: 1                 |   2
DateChecked:      1/9/2015          |   1/9/2015
UserChecked:      User1             |   User1
ProjectID:        1                 |   4
Projectname:      Nameless Project  |   Nameless Project
Projectcode:      P122-323          |   P122-323
Projecttype:      Type 3            |   Type 3
StatusID:         5                 |   4
StatusName:       Quote declined    |   Quote confirmed
-------------------------------------------------------
```

And this is exactly the the combination I want to prevent: a quote cannot be confirmed AND declined at the same time. It's an either or option.

Comment: So the "Statuses" table contains what the user actually picked, right ? That's not a referential table ? Otherwise, why is this a table variable ?

Comment: What actually is picked, is indeed recorded in a referential table. for example: Projects_Statuses or Incidents_Statuses. In the end, the users want to query out Projects or Incidents where, for example, the quotation has been confirmed. But if a quotation is confirmed AND declined at the same time, it would give false information, so I'm trying make it possible to overcome such results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'Quote confirmed' and 'Quote declined' cannot be both true.

Normally, this is the kind of condition that is checked by the software that maintains the database.

However, you could try something like this:

```
Status
------
StatusID
StatusType
ExclusiveStatus
```

And the rows would look like this:

```
1   Quote created     0
2   Quote accepted    0
3   Quote sent        0
4   Quote confirmed   1
5   Quote declined    1
```

Then you can write a trigger that will prevent more than one non-zero status from being used.

Comment: This is a good one. I also came up with having a column adding levels. For example, created = lvl 1. Accepted = lvl 2. Sent = lvl 3. Confirmed = lvl 4 and Declined is lvl 4 as well, but didn't come any further than that. A trigger is indeed a good idea to enforce that the occurrence of a level can not be used more than once.

With this level-column I'm also trying - what I haven't mentioned - to create this list of statuses a sort of chronological checklist: must start at level 1, before you can check any checkboxes which are at a higher level